# Draw the icons to the listview from imagelist?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-7

How to draw the icons to the listview from imagelist?
I'm using this code to change the selection color in my listview, but it doesn't have the icons from the imagelist.

```
procedure TForm2.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
x, y, i, w, h: integer;
begin
  with ListView1, Canvas do
  begin

    if odSelected in State then
    begin
      Brush.Color := clRed;
      Pen.Color := clWhite;
    end else
    begin
      Brush.Color := Color;
      Pen.Color := Font.Color;
    end;
    Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    FillRect(rect);
    h := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top + 1;
    x := Rect.Left + 1;
    y := Rect.Top + (h - TextHeight('Hg')) div 2;
    TextOut(x, y, Item.Caption);
    inc(x, Columns[0].Width);
    for i := 0 to Item.Subitems.Count - 1 do begin
      TextOut(x, y, Item.SubItems[i]);
      w := Columns[i + 1].Width;
      inc(x, w);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Delphi-7 had firemonkey? I think not... You have your question tagged `delphi-7` yet the code points to `firemonkey` which must be at least `delphi-xe2`. Which one is it?

Comment: @JerryDodge How did you came to that conclusion. It is pure VCL code, that works fine in Delphi 7.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I was mistaken the `TListItem` for a `TListBoxItem` My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to draw images yourself, too.

```
procedure DrawListViewItem(ListView: TListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; 
  State: TOwnerDrawState; SelectedBrushColor, SelectedFontColor, BrushColor, FontColor: TColor);
var
  x, y, i, w, h, iw, ih: integer;
begin
  with ListView do
  begin
    if odSelected in State then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := SelectedBrushColor;
      Canvas.Font.Color := SelectedFontColor;
    end else
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := BrushColor;
      Canvas.Font.Color := FontColor;
    end;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    Canvas.FillRect(rect);

    h := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top + 1;

    if Assigned(SmallImages) then
      begin
        iw := SmallImages.Width;
        ih := SmallImages.Height;
        x := Rect.Left + 1;
        if Item.ImageIndex >= 0 then 
          SmallImages.Draw(Canvas, Rect.Left + x, Rect.Top +(h - ih) div 2, Item.ImageIndex);
        x := x + iw + 2;
      end
    else
      begin
        iw := 0;
        ih := 0;
        x := Rect.Left + 1;
      end;

    y := Rect.Top + (h - Canvas.TextHeight('Hg')) div 2;
    Canvas.TextOut(x, y, Item.Caption);
    inc(x, Columns[0].Width - iw);
    for i := 0 to Item.Subitems.Count - 1 do begin
      Canvas.TextOut(x, y, Item.SubItems[i]);
      w := Columns[i + 1].Width;
      inc(x, w);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  DrawListViewItem(ListView1, Item, Rect, State, clRed, clWhite, ListView1.Color, ListView1.Font.Color);
end;
```

I have moved drawing code into separate function. That makes it reusable and a bit cleaner. Using `with` directly inside form method can have unwanted side effects. Same goes for double `with` clause, so I used only one (although I tend to avoid `with` completely in my code).

I have noticed that you used `Pen.Color`, but I changed that to `Font.Color`, because setting `Pen` has no effect whatsoever in your code, and I assume that you actually wanted to change color of the text.